# why we need vsync and hysnc in LCD driver?

Tags: graphics, framebuffer

I have a doubt in android/linux framebuffer part, that is why we need hysnc, vysnc. Because as I correctly remembered, these terms are used in case of CRT. But While we are using the LCD why we need these, we can use a simple  signal to indicate that row/column is completed, why we need to wait for some time to indicate hsync and vsync( time I mean HBP,HFP,VBP,VFP). Please clear my doubt on this.

Comment: Because, for historical reasons, that's how LCDs work.

Comment: LCDs feed the data to screen the same way as CRT (sequentally pixel by pixel the difference is only that they do not blink-darken the fluorescent material after each frame, and do not interleave lines) so if you move some object on screen out of sync sync then graphical fragments may occur (part of image shifting or even skew). For example move square really fast and you will see that its part is sometimes shifted by pixel

Comment: as @duskwuff said, for historical reason..! But why it has sustained is - we DO some work while we wait, so practically time is not wasted.